# Function to generate permutations of sequence with elements limited to 1 adjacent move

Tags: algorithm, sequence

Let's say there is a list of length n, which contains the letters A - char(n). I want to find the permutations in which each letter can only move adjacently or remain where it is. So tor each seq, there are three "set" permutations, cycled to the left, cycled to the right(list is considered cyclic), and the original list. I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to deal with the possible swaps in the middle of the list. Mainly, how the pairing for letters to be swapped can skip over letters. 
Ex: Permutations for list where n = 3 [ABC, CAB, BCA, ACB, CBA,BAC]
Also, the ABC and CAB are considered to be unique despite the elements having the same position relative to each other. Mainly looking for algorithm and not any specific language.
The basic rule is that the elements may be a maximum of 1 position away from its originally position in the list.

Comment: Can you please give an example of a permutation that would not be valid, perhaps from `n=4`?

Comment: A not valid permutation could be CBAD since there is no way for C to get to position 1, since it can only move 1 position left or right.

Comment: How many adjacent swaps are allowed to construct one permutation?

Comment: There is no limit to the number of swaps total, hoever each element may only move once per permutation. For n = 6 the maxmimum swaps to create one permutation is 3(3 pairs that can be swapped), and the lowest being one(excluding the original list).

Comment: How do we get from `ABC` to `BCA` with only one move each? Do you mean any permutation where an element is now a maximum of one step away from its position in the "original" / "ordered" permutation is valid? Or do you mean any permutation that can be achieved with a maximum of one adjacent swap per element is valid?

Comment: The first one, I used to the word "swap" loosely because of my previous attempts to solve. So yes, the element is a maximum of 1 position away from it's original position. 'code' ABC to BCA is every element shifting to the left 1.

Comment: Just to be clear, the unstated assumption is that adjacency is circular, right? So from `ABCD` you could go to `DBCA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll sketch an efficient enumeration strategy.

First let's solve the easier problem where there is no wraparound. There are two possibilities for the leftmost element. Either it stays put or moves right. If it moves right, then the element that it displaces must move left. We can enumerate the possibiltiies for the rest of the permutation recursively.

```
# this code is for the simpler problem, without wraparound
# the algorithm for the problem with wraparound is described in prose below

def perms_line(lst, j):
    if len(lst) - j < 2:
        print(lst)
    else:
        perms_line(lst, j + 1)
        lst[j], lst[j + 1] = lst[j + 1], lst[j]
        perms_line(lst, j + 2)
        lst[j], lst[j + 1] = lst[j + 1], lst[j]

perms_line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0)
```

Now let's consider wraparound. If two consecutive elements move right, then every element must move right. If two consecutive elements move left, then every element must move left. Handle these exceptional permutations separately.

At the outset, consider the leftmost element. Either it stays put, is swapped with the element to its right, or is swapped with the rightmost element. For each of these three possibilities (note: two if n = 2 or just one if n = 1), use the no-wraparound enumeration strategy on the rest of the permutation. I'll pass on writing the code, since it'll take some fiddling to get right.

Comment: [2,3,4,5,1] is also valid (see the comments under the original question).

Comment: @גלעדברקן That's one of the exceptional permutations.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just tried your code, which didn't list it.

Comment: This solution worked for me. In order to do the wraparound, I simply switched the first and last element before calling the function. J was set to 1, so the first element is not swapped, and len(lst) - j < 3, so that the last element is not swapped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK new approach:

```
function(String begin,String end)
```

1. if size of end == 1: print begin + end.
2. Loop end:
3. ch = end[i]
4. newString = remove index i from end
5. `function(begin + ch, newString)`

Comment: What do you mean by next available letter? For example, the first time the loops/recursion runs, won't the output be "a" x n?("aaa" if n = 3)

Comment: Okay, so lets say n = 3. First run the list is ABC, after the first recursive call, should the list be AB or BC? Or something different?

Comment: Should be BC my bad. my alg. is flawed but if you noticed that, then fixing this should be rather easy. I'll edit soon.

Comment: So I changed it a little bit. You send in the orginal sequence, then when you call the recursive function inside you do function(list[1:], n -1) which just removes the first letter of the list which I believe is what you are trying to do(might be wrong). But from there, I'm getting output like [ABC, CC, BBC, CC, CBC, CC], I'm guessing because of the position of the line break statement but I'm not sure. I can post my code if you would like, but I think this might be an algorithm problem

Comment: Ok used a different approach this time. try it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you need to find all the permutations of a circular sequence which can be generated by selecting a non-overlapping set of adjacent pairs and swapping the two elements in each pair.

An adjacent pair can be uniquely identified by the first element in the pair; a set of adjacent pairs is non-overlapping if it does not include two consecutive elements. Without the circularity aspect, that is just fibonacci encoding: The sets of non-adjacent elements (NA) can be generated recursively as follows:

```
NA({a1,a2,…,an}, T) = NA({a2,a3,…,an}, T)
                      ⋃ NA({a3,a4,…,an}, T ⋃ {a1})
NA({a}, T) = { T ⋃ {a} }
NA({}, T)  = { T }
```

It should be clear that there are `fibonacci(n + 1)` sets in the final result, since the count of NA(n) is the sum of the counts of NA(n-1) and NA(n-2).

To account for the circularity, we restrict the initial case by excluding the last element if we select the first one:

```
CNA({a1,a2,…,an}) = NA({a2,a3,…,an}, {})
                    ⋃ NA({a3,a4,…,an-1}, {a1})
```

Since that's just defined in terms of `NA`, we can see that the count of sets for `CNA` is `fibonacci(n) + fibonacci(n - 2)`.